# Protect localdb with a username and password

Tags: c#, localdb, mdf

Is there a way to protect my localdb?

I want to protect my localdb with a username and password because anyone can open the database (.mdf file installed with the application) with sql server management and access the database.

Comment: It depends on how much security you expect. Anyone who should be able to open the application needs the ability to open the database. You can hide the details somehow but it is only security by obscurity

Comment: When someone wants to open the database, I want him to enter the username and password to open the database for him

Comment: But what should happen when someone opens the application? Do you also want him to enter username and password?

Comment: There is nothing to stop an adminstrator user on the machine from doing whatever they want so you are probably wasting your time. Write a good contract stating you won't cover any support if they mess around with the database.

Comment: From the docs _If user database files are stored in a shared location, the database can be opened by anyone with file system access to that location by using an instance of LocalDB that they own_ I haven't used LocalDB much but I don't think you can password protect it. It's not made for that.

Comment: If you still can, maybe consider [SQLite(-cipher)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli)?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods The app needs to know the pass - so in fact the starting user can get this pass too. It is only security by obscurity

Comment: @SirRufo well, OP wrote somewhere User shall enter Password. That would be doable with a passworded SQLite file.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods There is no way to prevent an admin user debugging your app and reading off the cipher. As soon as it's running on their machine they can do anything.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes. That's as good as you get. But it's what OP seems to want to be doing.